# Is Google Colab Pro available in any state?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm Italian and I'm interested in trying the paid version of Google Colab but reading the FAQ it seems that the service is only available in U.S.
Anyone know where I can find information about it?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is a poor fit for SO. "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and
"[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Colab Pro signup page](https://colab.research.google.com/signup), Colab Pro is indeed available in the US only at present.

[image]

My guess would be that Colab Pro will be similar to other Google services, which generally roll out across countries after an initial US launch.

Comment: Frustratingly, it's still US only.

Comment: As of December 2020 It is available for US and Canada

Comment: I took a look yesterday and there are more countries now :) Still, Italy is not among them